# Isolated atom absorbs photon at relativistic speeds

Tags: special-relativity, photons, momentum, energy-conservation

I've been studying a type of problem wherein we initially have a photon (with (lab frame) energy $E_L$) and atom, both moving in the $+\hat{x}$-direction, with respective speeds $c$ (of course) and $v_i$. The atom and photon then collide, and the atom absorbs the photon. Ignoring any of the specific mechanics of the collision itself aside from the fact that when the atom absorbs the photon its internal energy increases by $E_A$, we can write a conservation of energy equation:
$$E_L+\gamma_i m_0 c^2 = \gamma_f\left(m_0+\frac{E_A}{c^2}\right)c^2$$
My question is: why do we have to consider $E_A$ as contributing to the mass of the atom, rather than just the total energy of the system, and why can't we instead write

$$E_L+\gamma_i m_0 c^2 = \gamma_f m_0 c^2 + \gamma_f E_A?$$

I know that this is mathematically equivalent to the above statement, but conceptually it is very different. One way to tell that it's conceptually different is that if we use the "mass increases" logic, we also get the **correct** conservation of momentum equation:

$$\frac{1}{c}E_L + \gamma_i m_0 v_i=\gamma_f \left(m_0 + \frac{E_A}{c^2}\right)v_f$$

But if we use the logic that the total energy of the system increases by $E_A$, then we get an incorrect equation,

$$\frac{1}{c}E_L + \gamma_i m_0 v_i=\gamma_f m_0 v_f,$$

because the momentum of the particle under this assumption isn't affected by the internal energy of the atom.

Comment: Because after the absorption of the photon, the energy of the atom increases even in the rest frame of the atom.

Comment: @Ghoster fixed that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

> why do we have to consider $E_A$ as contributing to the mass of the atom

This is just because of how you chose to define $E_A$. You defined it as a change in internal energy. Internal energy times $c^2$ is mass. So changing internal energy necessarily changes mass.

> why can't we instead write …

You absolutely can write it that way instead. As you say it is mathematically equivalent.

The conceptual difference is fine. That just shows a relationship between the concepts.

> momentum of the particle under this assumption isn't affected by the internal energy of the atom

This is incorrect. Momentum is affected by internal energy. Momentum is affected by mass and mass is internal energy divided by $c^2$.